# Transferring a range from 1 Spreadsheet to another without overwriting the current range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script I just can't seem to get quite right.

Spreadsheet1 people fill out as they have a "Hot Job", basically this creates a paper trail/transparency for the person in charge of said job.

Spreadsheet2 is more of reporting tool, how many came through their reason and from what customer.

Spreadsheet1 will get a new tab 'Sheet' each week, at the end of each week I want to send the entire range to spreadsheet2 without over writing any information that is already on spreadsheet2 via a time-driven trigger. IE getLastRow() then insert new data below.

This is where I am currently, this will do what I ask of it some of the time. Sometimes I get a "The coordinates or dimesnions of the range are invalid" error, I don't know why because sometimes it works.

```
function hotJob() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dropDown = ss.getSheetByName("Dropdown");
  var sheetName =dropDown.getRange("H2").getValue();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var data = sheet.getRange("A2:O").getValues();
  var rowsInData = data[0].length;
  var colsInData = data[0].length;
  var mdURL = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Dj34hO55q_AYISk0TxpCyVl55rSoeOGpZ1dmuJli8IE/edit#gid=2081965371');
  var mdSheet = mdURL.getSheetByName("Hot Jobs");
  var mdLastRow = mdSheet.getLastRow(); 

  mdSheet.insertRows(rowsInData);
  mdSheet.getRange(mdLastRow, 1, rowsInData, colsInData).setValues(data);

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I have searched and tried multiple options I have found on here, but couldn't adapt any of them to work properly for my situation either.

Thanks,
Tyler

Answer (score 0):

You have two identical values here

```
var rowsInData = data[0].length;
var colsInData = data[0].length;
```

The first one shouldn't have the `[0]` before length.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for the response.  I made the change to reflect the [0] and now I am getting a "The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid." error.